# Can I create a "multi-windowed" command-line Python program?

Tags: python, multi-window, tui

I'm doing some experiments with TensorFlow on my new computer, and I'm very satisfied with the results so far so I decided to turn one of them into a fully-fledged CLI program. It's a machine learning model that tries to predict the course of Ethereum, a cryptocurrency. I'm not doing it to make money with it, just trying to see how accurate I could get it. I know far too little about stocks, exchanges and what have you to actually turn a profit anyway.

The way I've got it so far is as such: I have a `trainer.py` which trains the model and a `main.py` which takes the weights from the checkpoints generated by the trainer, asks the user for new input data and spits out its prediction.

**What I want:**

- The user can input commands and generally interact with the program.
- Logs get printed to the log window (obviously), which scrolls automatically.
- As soon as a new OHLC block gets generated by the model, it prints it out onto the OHLC window.

  - Importantly, the library I'm using for drawing them ([termgraph](https://github.com/sgeisler/termgraph)) assumes a full-size terminal window; not the limited frame it gets.

I've tried dashed, but it wasn't able to satisfy these conditions.

Would I need to do some weird, hacky low-level stuff like firing off separate processes for all of these things or something? To be honest, low-level things like that kinda scare me.

If this post is a bit non-descript or vague, please let me know and I'll try my best to give as much information as possible. (Additionally, English isn't my first language.)

[image: I've painstakingly made this mockup in GIMP, of all programs]

Comment: There are a bunch of options here, from low-level [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/library/curses.html?highlight=curses#module-curses) to [a bunch of others](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=python+tui+library).

Comment: What is that image you have shown? Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yep, it's a mockup I made in GIMP of all programs.

Comment: @Chris Curses is definitely a possibility, but I consider it more of a last resort. py_cui could work, though. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is the right site for this question, you're asking for library recommendations which is generally not allowed, and as you said this is a bit vague. Does https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ seem like it might be a better place to ask this?

Comment: Most projects use some wrapper around ncurses for this